# QuickStart Guide: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found

Tags: identityserver4

Attempting to work through the quickstart guide on IdentityServer4. I was following instructions in the following document: [Protecting an API using Client Credentials](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html). I got to the point in the document "Navigating to the controller https://localhost:6001/identity on a browser should return a 401 status code." Instead I received the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).

Any idea what would cause this issue?

Comment: I'd suggest to read it through again and perhaps download the sample code on [Github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/main/samples/Quickstarts) to compare!

Comment: Ya, I ended up finding that after I posted the question. github sample appears to work, looks like it's a issue with latest version of dependencies.

Comment: Can you post a copy of your startup class?

Comment: Yeah copy startup code on API project if possible. As a side note, can u confirm you have `services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")` in ur code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have these two lines in your startup class?

```
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: uh, ya, it's in the guide

Comment: Can you post a copy of your startup class?

Comment: I ended up using different tech for authentication